# An error on storing a value on a parameter on the second step of for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement the GAN structure. 
In my code, I obtain the loss of discrimination model for the first batch of data, but for the second batch, I get the following error.

```
ipdb> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar221 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar221/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
         [[node mul_210/ReadVariableOp (defined at C:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_9394]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please put the code/traceback content inside code markup so it's readable.

Comment: Mohsen, could you post more of your own code? The section that defines the graph would probably be useful in debugging this error. Or, if you are using one of the pre-made estimators, the code that instantiates and configures the estimator.